# File Importing From one Dir to another Dir

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

so basically my dir looks like this:

/node:

~/libs/lib.js

~/projects/main/script.js

and i want to import (the entire file) "lib" [\Node\libs\lib.js] into "script" [\Node\Projects\main\script.js],
how do i do that?

thanks in advance,
-Gzrespect

Comment: You mean you want to copy the codes from lib.js into script.js?

Comment: i want to use it like a library

like in python 
ìmport random` 
and exactly thaat but for node and the lib being on my local files

Answer (score 0):

Since your script.js is in the "main" folder of "Projects" folder, so you have to go 2 levels deeper. Add this codes into top part of your script.js. Please make sure you have exported in lib.js, module.exports = connection;

```
  const connection = require("../../libs/lib");
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't import the entire file from one directory to another but you can export the any Data Types primitive(int, string etc.) & non-primitive(objects & arrays).

```
const sum = (a,b) => return a + b;
const object = {}
const array = []

exports.module = {sum, object, array};
```

later in file in which you want to use that functions, objects and array..

```
const {sum, object, array} = require("file path");
```